# Lavaan bad goodness of fit values

Tags: r

Hey I'm currently writing my master's thesis and I'll have to conduct a PLS-SEM (using `lavaan` package). The model I run is based on my research model to test the stated hypothesis. When I run the `sem()` function in R the goodness of fit measures **RMSEA** and **TLI** are really bad.
How can I fix this to get a better model fit?

[That's my research model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrykK.png)

```
mmodel2 <- '
        # measurement model
        MOD =~ moderation
        USE =~ DummySSOuse
        FAM =~ usageFrequ
        SELF =~ selfeffic1 + selfeffic2 + selfeffic3 + selfeffic4 + selfeffic5 + selfeffic6 + selfeffic7 + selfeffic8 + secPrecaut + selfProt1 + selfProt2 + selfProt3
        PBE =~ percBenef1 + percBenef2 + percBenef3 + percEoU1 + percEoU2 + percEoU3
        SENS =~ fullName + email + phoneNo + birthday + location + relaStatus + friendList + photos
        PRI =~ percRisk1 + percRisk2 + percRisk3 + percRisk4 + percRisk5 + percRisk6 + percRisk7 + percRisk8 + percRisk9

        # regression
        PBE ~ FAM + SELF
        PRI ~ SELF + SENS
        SELF ~ FAM
        USE ~ PBE + PRI
        PBE ~ MOD
        
        # variance estimation of exogeneous variables
        FAM ~~ FAM
        SENS ~~ SENS

        # covariance estimation of exogeneous variables
        FAM ~~ SENS
        
        # residual variance estimation for endogenous variables
        SELF  ~~ SELF
        PBE  ~~ PBE 
        PRI ~~ PRI
        USE ~~ USE
        MOD ~~ MOD
        
        # estimating covariance of residuals
        PBE ~~ PRI
'


fit_mmodel  <- sem(mmodel2, data=dataC)
test_mmodel <- summary(fit_mmodel, standardized=TRUE, fit.measures=TRUE, rsquare=TRUE)
```

This is what I get in the R output:

```
  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of free parameters                         85
                                                      
  Number of observations                           122
                                                      
Model Test User Model:
                                                      
  Test statistic                              2136.996
  Degrees of freedom                               656
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                              3363.118
  Degrees of freedom                               703
  P-value                                        0.000

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.443
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.403

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

  Loglikelihood user model (H0)              -7559.906
  Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)      -6491.408
                                                      
  Akaike (AIC)                               15289.811
  Bayesian (BIC)                             15528.153
  Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (BIC)        15259.401

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.136
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.130
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.142
  P-value RMSEA <= 0.05                          0.000
```

Here's a link to the .csv data file: https://gitlab.com/aenglhart/pls-sem-data.git

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to answer this question, no data, no model, just the function used. To get a better fit, get a better model?

Comment: I just updated my post.